# Android App TensorFlow Google Cloud ML

Tags: android, machine-learning, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am studying how to use TensorFlow together with Google Cloud ML on an Android App.
I already found this [post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40823051/using-google-cloud-ml-with-android-app)
As far as I understand from this post and what I already found on google I always have to deploy a trained model (i.e. the Tensorflow Graph?) first?
There is no way to use Google Cloud ML to send in  data values and train a TensorFlow Model in this Cloud?

So the only way is: deploy a model, send data values to the google cloud and receive a prediction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an API for running training jobs in the Cloud. For an example, see the [training quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/training-models).

Note that there is not currently a straightforward way to perform streaming training directly using the CloudML service, but you could get creative with PubSub, Cloud DataFlow, or other technologies.

Were you looking for a streaming solution or is the job-based solution sufficient for your needs?

Comment: Well actually I wanna send data to the cloud and train the model, after some time send some new data and retrain this model, and use it for predictions

Comment: Follow-up questions: would you be replacing or augmenting the data? How much data do you anticipate "sending" each time you want to retrain?

Comment: I would augmenting the data. It should not be that much data. Right now, everything is done with WEKA on the phone: Data is collected, as soon as there is enough data from the user a model can be trained, trained model is stored on the phone, which can be used for prediction. If there is more data a new model is trained/retrained.  This is not a good solution. So I wanted to send a users data to a cloud, train the model there, use this model for a user's prediction

Comment: You could write a TensorFlow training script that loads data from a particular GCS bucket (configurable via command-line arguments). When new data is available on the phone, upload it to GCS, use the training API to start a training job that loads the data from the GCS, and when training is done, either download the model to the phone or deploy it in the cloud for predictions.